# I tried to apply pagination to the search results, but the search condition was initialized the moment I pressed the page number

Tags: python, django

I have a one question

I tried to apply pagination to the search results, but the search condition was initialized the moment I pressed the page number.

after search by keyword this url is excuted
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/wm/myshortcut/go_to_skil_note_search_page_for_all/?q=test`

and after press pagi number this url is excuted
http://127.0.0.1:8000/wm/myshortcut/go_to_skil_note_search_page_for_all/?page=2

url i want is this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/wm/myshortcut/go_to_skil_note_search_page_for_all/?q=test&page=2
```

is this possible?

Do I need to modify the view code to do this?
Or do I need to edit the template?

view is this

```
class go_to_skil_note_search_page_for_all(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = MyShortCut
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['wm/myshortcut_list_for_search2.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in self.request.GET:
            query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        else:
            query=" "

        print("query ::::::::::::::: ", query)
        print('seach user: {}  search word: {} ################################################'.format(self.request.user, query))
        qs = MyShortCut.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=query) | Q(filename__contains=query) | Q(content1__contains=query) | Q(content2__contains=query)).order_by('created')
        print("qs : ", qs)
        return qs
```

template for pagi number:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
   {% bootstrap_pagination page_obj size="small" justify_content="center" %}
{% endif %}
```

thanks for let me know ~!

Comment: I have a little confusion, do you want to show something like q=test&page=2, if that all that you need you can do that by adding: 
?q=test&page={{ object_context.next_page_number }}, Is that what you asked?

Comment: excuse me  maybe Are you telling me to edit the template?

Comment: yes will be like that: <a href="?q=test&page_number=1">&laquo; first</a> and do that in the rest of the elements that have this query

Comment: thanks for idea it's sloved